# Which files are displayed or executed after login?

Tags: terminal, login, motd

I'm using an embedded Linux distribution (Lime2) on a custom ARM board.

On login via SSH, the following is displayed:

```
root@mybox ~ # ssh localhost
root@localhost's password:

 _     _                  ____
| |   (_)_ __ ___   ___  |___ \
| |   | | '_ ` _ \ / _ \   __) |
| |___| | | | | | |  __/  / __/
|_____|_|_| |_| |_|\___| |_____|


welcome to mybox!
Last login: Wed May  4 19:50:28 2016 from localhost
Load: 1.01, 1.10, 0.86 - Board: 27.3°C - Memory: 929Mb
root@mybox ~ #
```

I'm wondering where the individual components of this prompt are coming from. This is what I figured out:

- The password prompt line is coming from `/bin/login`, obviously
- I have no idea about the Lime2 banner is coming from
- The welcome message is what I entered into /etc/motd
- The 'Last login' line is generated by `/bin/login` or some `PAM` service, I suppose
- The 'Load' line I found hidden in `/etc/bash.bashrc.custom`

So... apart from `/etc/motd`, which other files are displayed or executed before spawning the login shell? Where is this Lime2 banner coming from?

Comment: search banner line from ssh config and  post in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `strace` to show all `open` syscalls, which will print out all accessed files.

To trace a **local login** session, run this in a root shell:

```
strace -f -e open login 2>&1
```

To trace an **ssh login** session:

```
strace -f -e open -p <sshd_pid> 2>&1
```

For example, first determine the PID of the ssh daemon:

```
router:~# ps -ef | grep ssh
root      4816     1  0 May04 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
root      6584  5941  0 01:18 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@pts/0
root      6647  6381  0 01:23 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto ssh
```

Then trace using option `-p` followed by PID of sshd:

```
strace -f -e open -p 4816 2>&1
```

Now login using ssh from another terminal.